# Read .lua files in .net ( LuaInterface )

Tags: .net, vb.net, lua, luainterface

i have a Question :

How can i `parse / read` `.lua` files with `.net.`

Sample.lua :

```
TestValues = {
        ["test1"] = {
        [1] = "value1",
        [2] = "value2",
        [3] = "value3",
        }
    }
```

How i can get the data : `value1, value2, value3`?

I cant seem to find any documentation on the internet

Comment: The LuaInterface project page suggests to prefer using nlua over it.https://code.google.com/p/luainterface/

Comment: @hjpotter92 I wouldn't refer to **Google Code** because this service may vanish in not far future. [Github](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) stores the main project page now.

Comment: @Youka Isn't that exactly what the google-code page said? Specifically quoting: "_Over the last few years I've found very little time to work on LuaInterface. Certain platforms such as Mono/Xamarin and WinRT aren't supported well (if at all) and there are still quite a few bugs open.

I would like to suggest that the community look towards Vinicius Jarina's project on Github called NLua moving forward._"